# Overflow-Y doesn't work while height is specified

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I'm working on a new menu and I'm trying to have my content in a setup like this:

```
div with position fixed, defined height and overflow hidden
    div with position relative, overflow Y auto and defined height bigger than parent
    /div
/div
```

here is my [edited] jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bp9qdfb9/

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet within the question, links to external resources will die, and when they do, the question will be useless to future users

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bp9qdfb9/ would that do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overflow should be assigned to the container of the element that overflows:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper > .container > .page {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrapper > .container > .page > .wrap-in {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="wrap-in">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```